# How to access method of an object in the object?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am trying to condense my code, so I want to create object instead of having to create labels each time I need one.

However, I can't figure out how to be able to change attributes of the object-labels using `.config`. I've tried using `objectvariable.config(...)`, but that doesn't work. Neither does using a method like in the following:

```
class title_label():
    def __init__(self):
        self = tkinter.Label(root)
        self.pack(side='left')

    def update(self, text):
        self.config(text=text)
```

Error-message is: `objectvariable object has no attribute config`.

How can I use `.config` on an object containing a label?

Comment: `self = tkinter.Label(root)` Why are you assigning to `self`?  That's almost certainly not what you really wanted.

Comment: You're getting that error because you didn't define a `config()` method for you class — only one named `update()`. Why were you expecting it to have one?

Comment: @martineau `tkinter.Label` has a `config()` method. And since I assigned the Label to `self` I assumed that I can access the method this way..

Comment: Rick: Ah, I see. Well, that assignment doesn't actually change the instance of your class, merely what object is associated with the local variable named `self` within the `__init__()` method. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). I also suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
class title_label():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.label = tkinter.Label(root)   # <<< 'label' field here
        self.label.pack(side='left')
    
    def update(self, text):
        self.label.config(text=text)
```

`self` hold the reference to the class itself. `label` is something that your class is supposed to *hold* not to *be*. Another approach would be to derive from the `Label` class, but for what it is worth storing the label in the field should be good enough for you.

Comment: I don't really get why, but this works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rick_2650 You can mark the answer as 'accepted' by clicking the 'tick' icon next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you made your class a ***subclass*** of `tkinter.Label` then it would have inherited a [`config()` method](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) from it.
Here's an example of how that might be done:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TitleLabel(tk.Label):
    def update(self, text):
        self.config(text=text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    title_lbl = TitleLabel(root, text='Initial Text')
    title_lbl.pack(side='left')

    root.after(1000, lambda: title_lbl.update('CHANGED!'))  # Update after 1 sec.
    root.mainloop()
```

But as you can see, there wouldn't really be much point of doing so, since the only thing `update()` does is forward to call on the base class.